# output for str.join() method is not consistent

Tags: python, string

Lets assign two variables:

```
>>> a_id = 'c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad953582'
>>> u_id = '59958a11a6ad4d8b39707a70'
```

Right output:

```
>>> a_id+u_id
'c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad95358259958a11a6ad4d8b39707a70'
```

Wrong output:

```
>>> str.join(a_id,u_id)
'5c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535829c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535829c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535825c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535828c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad953582ac99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535821c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535821c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad953582ac99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535826c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad953582ac99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad953582dc99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535824c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad953582dc99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535828c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad953582bc99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535823c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535829c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535827c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535820c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535827c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad953582ac99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535827c99faf24275d476d84e0c8f0ad9535820'
```

Now consider this case, the output is correct now:

```
>>> a="asdf"
>>> b="asdfsdfsd"

>>> str.join(a,b)
'aasdfsasdfdasdffasdfsasdfdasdffasdfsasdfd'
```

Confirming the type of all variables in the example:

```
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>

>>> type(a_id)
<class 'str'>

>>> type(u_id)
<class 'str'>
```

**Edit**

I just realized the second case in the output was not quite what I expected as well. I was using join method in a wrong way.

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is your question?

Comment: `str.join()` is an **unbound** method. You asked Python to join the individual characters of `user_id` together with `app_id` as the joining string.

Comment: You normally use `" joining string ".join(iterable_of_strings)`

Comment: So `str.join(a, b)` is the same thing as `a.join(b)`, where `b` is an iterable. Strings are iterables, producing each separate character, so you get `b[0] + a + b[1] + a + b[2] + a + ... + a + b[len(b) - 1]`

Comment: `.join` is not for adding two strings, thats what the `+` is for. `.join` is for consuming an iterable to form a string, using a "filler" between each element.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `b[len(b) - 1]` is the same as `b[-1]`.

Comment: @iBug: yes, I know that. I used `len(b) - 1` deliberately, to echo common notations indicating a variable-size sequence concatenation. My illustration is *not Python code* but a mathematical notation.

Answer (score 5):

`str.join(a, b)` is equivalent to `a.join(b)`, provided `a` is a str object and `b` is an iterable. Strings are always iterable, as you will be iterating though each characters in it when you're iterating over a string.

This is basically "insert a copy of `a` between every element of `b` (as an iterable)", so if `a` and `b` are both strings, a copy of `a` is inserted into every pair of letters in `b`. For example:

```
>>> str.join(".", "123456")
'1.2.3.4.5.6'
```

If you simply want to concatenate two strings, `+` is enough, not `join`:

```
>>> "." + "123456"
'.123456'
```

If you really want `join`, put the strings in a list and use an empty string as "delimiter":

```
>>> str.join('', ['123', '456', '7890'])
'1234567890'
>>> ''.join(['123', '456', '7890'])
'1234567890'
```